# Is present perfect acceptable? - Has this area attracted new residents lately?

Tags: present-perfect, past-vs-present-perfect

Is the following sentence grammatically correct or it is awkward:

"Has this area attracted new residents lately?"

Should I instead say:

"Did this area attract new residents lately?"

Comment: I don't see any problem. What is your concern?

Comment: I was wondering whether I can use Present Perfect with "lately". @VictorBazarov said it's Ok. The Present Perfect is really difficult for me ...

Answer (score 2):

It has always bothered me that, while Present Perfect is used when talking about present, about *now*, it is allowed to combine in the same sentence, like in your example, "*have attracted*" with "*lately*" (or "*recently*"), which to me sounds like an adverb that points to the *past*, and not *present*.

On the other hand, the point of using Present Perfect is to emphasize *the result* over some specific point in time of the event.  So, yes, it is *perfectly* OK (pun intended).

Comment: Present Perfect is not merely Present. It is a Present that started in the past, and talks of a period of time that started in the past and has continued from there to the actual present you are referring to.